# How prevent rotation until AsyncTask is not ended

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I have noticed that if I try to rotate the device while an `AsyncTask` is running the App crashes.
This [seems caused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19949013/the-asynctask-fails-when-i-rotate-the-device-to-landscape) by the fact `Activity` is destroyed and recreated in the rotation.

To avoid this I want to capure the rotation event and execute it only if there aren't active `AsyncTask`s... if there are `AsyncTask`s that are active, the app should pause the rotation and execute it when these are completed.

How I could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible to pause screen rotation. You can only stop it entirely using configChanges in your activity manifest entry (but that is bad practice). What you should do is to put your async task in retained fragment. Until recently you could use [Activity.getLastNonConfigurationInstance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getLastNonConfigurationInstance())  and [Activity.onRetainNonConfigurationInstance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance())  to keep reference to AsyncTask between Activity being destroyed and recreated but now its deprecated. But you can still use it.

read here for more information: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()

Also:

> if I try to rotate the device during AsincTask the App crashes

this actually should not happen, it is possible that you keep reference to your Activity in AsyncTask and use it after it is destroyed. This is called reference leak. To avoid it keep reference to your Activity in WeakReference, also if your AsyncTask is an inner class, then make it static. If it is possible, destroy your asynctask in Activity.onDestroy - by cancelling it, in async task check if it is cancelled and stop processing. If you use it to download things then consider retained fragment or IntentService.

Answer (score 2):

Re-design your app and use a fragment with `setRetainInstance(true)`. Put your AsyncTask inside the fragment. This is the right thing to do in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Do not do that. Instead, handle everything correctly through orientation changes.

A worker `Fragment` with an `AsyncTask` in it is a good solution.
The fragment stays across orientation changes so the task does not get interrupted and always reports to the correct `Activity` via Fragment's `getActivity()`.

This tutorial shows exactly how to do this 
http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

Answer (score 1):

You could check if your `AsyncTask` is running and, if it is, prevent the application from rotating. Something like this would do the trick:

```
if (myAsyncTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)
{
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
    else
    {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
}
```

The above code will check if you `AsyncTask` is running and, if it is, get the current screen orientation and lock it. You could add a similar check to unlock rotation if the `AsyncTask` is no longer running.